# Create, Insert, Update or Delete XML using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, xml, function

So completed my uni stuff using a little help from you fantastic programmers out there and a few all nighters to go as far as I could with manipulating XML data through Javascript. Now I'm done for the summer and my dear old mother has asked me to create her a basic site for her maths tutoring service with info and prices etc... I was thinking as she doesn't need much I would go in for using XML again but this time not restricted on the use of PHP to Create new elements/nodes, update or delete.

I was going to create her a basic booking system with a little admin panel for editing entries etc... As the information doesn't really need to be too secure the use of XML seems to be alright for the purpose.

My question is Does anyone know of any clean basic functions that can be used to this end with XML using PHP ?? In terms of functions I would mean things like Create/Insert, Edit/Update, Delete etc...

Any help or even a site that has a decent tutorial on it would be great as I've gone through youtube and there isn't anything decent or clean and simple.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use the DOM methods to create/edit/delete nodes from an XML.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Just curious, why do you want to play with XML, may be the easier choice would be a database as simple as SQLite http://php.net/sqlite.

Comment: Thanks for the info there dude. Yeah I know I could just use MySQL and a small database but to be honest I've wanted to do more work with XML and thought this would be a good excuse to have a go at it. I also thought it would be good to have an XML example in my portfolio for later on as well as just having the code all there just incase I need it for something even more simple.